# Javascript: Get a variable name as a string

Tags: javascript

I often use functions like this one:

```
function elem(name){
    return document.getElementById(name);
}
```

Which is used like so:

```
var box = elem('box');
```

Often, the name of the variable I'm creating is the same as the string passed to the `elem` function.

How can I create a function that returns an element with the same id as the variable name?

Comment: Do you realize you're re-inventing the wheel with that function, right ? That said there's nothing I know to do what you wish, maybe you can just drop the variable and use the function call instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function elem(name){
    window[name]=document.getElementById(name);
}
```

Now, `elem('box');` will create global variable `box = document.getElementById('box');` which you can use.

Sample Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="box" onclick="hi();">box</div>  

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function elem(name){
        window[name]=document.getElementById(name);
    }
    function hi(){
        elem('box');
        box.style.border='1px solid #ccc';
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you can't. The function has no way to know what the variable name is.

The closest you could come would be to use a horrible, *horrible* hack and create a global:

```
function box (element_id) {
    window[element_id] = document.getElementById(element_id);
}

box('foo');
```

… but even that does the opposite of what you've asked for (creating the variable name from the string instead of the other way around).

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I'll test it and play around a bit.

Answer (score 0):

better make a namespace like

```
var ns = {};
['box', 'box2'].forEach(function (el) { ns[el] = document.getElementById(el); });
```

access with

```
ns.box.innerHtml = 'foo';
```

Comment: I'd rather it not use an object. It does make sense, just I still want it as an independent variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the DOM methods available without needing to generate a variable from the element ID.
Example, instead of using

```
var elem = document.getElementById("box");
elem.innerHTML = "Test";
```

you can directly use:

```
box.innerHTML = "Test";
```

But if you really need a variable from the same name for other reasons, I think can be done is using the `eval()` function like so:

```
function box(elem){
   eval("var "+ elem + " = document.getElementById('" + elem+ "');");
}
```